# Хочу построить выражение

Tags: jquery

найти элемент .list li не имеющий класс .decor
в нем найти и сравнить высоту элементов .text и .img
если высота у .img больше чем у .text в 1.7
то добавляем к .list li атрибут style со значением "width:70%;margin:0 auto 50px;" и присваиваем класс .decor

```
    <ul class="list">
      <li>
        <div class="text">...</div>
        <div class="img">...</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Сделал пока только это:

```
$('.list li').not('.decor').addClass('decor');
```

Comment: @Tank, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Разобрался:
Выражение правильное. 
Моя ошибка в том что не верный код html показал.
Доин из сравниваемых элементов не является непосредсвенным потомком li

Comment: Спасибо RubaXa !!!

 $('.list li:not(.decor)').each(function (){
  var
     $li = $(this)
   , $img = $li.children('.img')
   , $box = $li.find('.box')
   , factor = $img.height() / $box.height()
  ;

  if( factor > 1.5 ){
   $li
    .addClass('decor')
    .css({ width: '70%', margin: '0 auto 50px' })
   ;
  }
 });

Comment: @Tank, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/M3Pqy/ — если я правильно понял вашу задачу

```
$('.list li:not(.decor)').each(function (){
    var
          $li = $(this)
        , $img = $li.children('.img')
        , $text = $li.children('.text')
        , factor = $img.height() / $text.height()
    ;

    if( factor > 1.7 ){
        $li
            .addClass('decor')
            .css({ width: '70%', margin: '0 auto 50px' })
        ;
    }
});
```

Comment: Почти работает )
Почему то всем элементам добавился класс .decor и style

Comment: http://tanko.ru/m/

Comment: <pre>$('.list li:not(.decor)').each(function (){
  var
     $li = $(this)
   , $img = $li.children('.img')
   , $text = $li.children('.box')
   , factor = $img.height() / $text.height()
  ;

  if( factor > 1.9 ){
   $li
    .addClass('decor')
    .css({ width: '70%', margin: '0 auto 50px' })
   ;
  }
 });</pre>

Comment: children это непосредвствееный элемент???

Comment: 1. Поверьте, скрипт работает нормально, просто сама задача поставлена не корректно, её нужно решать средствами CSS, а не js.
2. children — http://api.jquery.com/children/